# how to assign value of an dynamically array collection to check box?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

```
 protected function inital():void
    {
        var _cb:CheckBox;
        var _formitem:FormItem;
        for( var i:int =0;i<program.list.length;i++)
        {
            _formitem = new FormItem();
            _formitem.label = employee.list.emp_name;
            _cb = new CheckBox();
            _cb.styleName="gridCheckBox";
            _cb.selected = (employee.list[i].emp_id == 'Y'?true:false);
            _formitem.addElement(_cb);
            Dynamic_Check.addElement(_formitem);
             }
         }
```

i am retreving a  list value from java side  in a Value object name as Employee where i h've declare the list an array collection which contain two field emp_name , emp_id and i am assign these value to label of check box and emp_id which is in (y or N format) but i am unable to see that check box label  as well as its  selection. IN VO, i just declare  List as a  array collection .public var list:ArrayCollection  = new ArrayCollection();

Answer (score 0):

Either use **CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE** on the ArrayCollection to update you buttons or use **BindingUtils.bindProperty** to bind the labels to the buttons.